# Detecting lack of gems in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I do `bundle install --without development test` before my RoR application working in production because I want to remove gems only used in development or test, but the other day, this caused the problem.
I wrote some code and it works in development, but it contained module provided by the gem, which was installed as development gem's dependence. I used unintentionally so I cannot noticed by deployment failed. So I want to detect it. I'm using CI, so maybe I can notice if I do same `bundle install` as in production and something rails kicked, but if I do so, CI will take a long time so I don't really want to. I'd love to hear what you think.

edit: I think you haven't got my point yet, so let me explain it again.

for example, my Gemfile is like below;

```
ruby '2.5.7'

gem 'rails', '5.2.2.1'

gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'

gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'

...

group :development, :test do

  gem 'overcommit'
  gem 'rails_best_practices'
  gem 'rubocop' # <- this gem also install unicode_display_width(which has `Unicode::DisplayWidth`) as dependency
end

group :development do
  gem 'brakeman'
  gem 'debase'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', require: false
  gem 'ridgepole'
  gem 'ruby-debug-ide', '0.6.0'
...
end

group :test do
  gem 'simplecov'
  ...
end
```

and I used `Unicode::DisplayWidth` in my application because I totally thought it was the library ruby originally has(like csv). I don't want to do something like this again, but I may do carelessly, so I want to detect it.

Comment: Try the suggestion from kurupt_89 below. If you do `cat .bundle/config` you should see the setting that you set via the `--without` flag (among others). You can manually edit that file, or run the config delete command. The --without flag is a little goofy in that, by default, it writes it as a config setting and persists across bundle commands even when you stop passing it

Comment: sorry for my clumsy english. I add information with my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what your problem is from your description. But have a look at `bundle list` to view installed gems https://bundler.io/man/bundle-list.1.html

Also, try `bundle config` and if you see any `without`'s that you were not expecting, you can run `bundle config --delete without` to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try and paraphrase what I think you're asking based on your updated question:

You want your CI pipeline to detect if you used a library in your code that wasn't made available via bundler*, but you don't want to slow your CI pipeline down with another bundle install command.

If that's the case, we have 3 separate pipelines/processes that we use:

- CI/CD pipeline on Semaphore to run our automated tests. This pipeline won't catch the type of error described above
- Separate pipeline using Heroku's [review app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps) feature which builds a "live" application using dummy/seed data, but production-like settings (e.g. `bundle install --without development text`). This *may* catch the type of error described above; you may have to *use* the review app to trigger the error and sometimes we don't
- We also have a separate staging environment where user testing occurs, which is also production-like. This is where that type of error should definitely be identified (because we have users test features here by using the site)

This has been a common strategy at a number of projects I've worked on for catching this kind of error before it deploys to production.

* Because bundler in production is run `bundle --without development test`